# clearTimeout() not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

//The code given below is my looping function using setTimeout()

```
if(gameLevel==1){
        x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 3000);
    }else if(gameLevel==2){
        x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 2500);
    }
    else if(gameLevel==3){
        x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 2000);
    }
    else if(gameLevel==4){
        x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 1500);
    }
    else if(gameLevel==5){
        x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 1000);
    }
```

//I want to stop this setTimeout() when the variable playerLife<1, I used clearTimeout() as given below, but its not working, Kindly Help, Thanks a lot in advance!

```
if(playerLife<1)
    {
        console.log(playerLife);
      clearTimeout(x);


    }
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @vijith You can use .stop() to stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements. Pls try clearTimeout() after stop().

Comment: @Bhum Its a part of a small typing game which I am working on  right now, Words from  an array will randomly generate on the screen in different positions, All those random generation and everything are in gameengine(), which  runs continuously  by setTimeout() mentioned in the code, When the playerLife value reaches 0, I want to stop the settimeout function to stop, but here the settimeout is still working and words are continue to generate, I put an alert inside the if statement and its working when the player life is less than 1, still the clearTimeout is not working

Comment: @VeenaK.Suresh I used clearTimeout as mentioned in my question, but its not working, the function gameEngine is running continuously using setTimeout(), I want to stop that when the if condition becomes true!, Thankyou

Comment: It would be great if you create a fiddle showing the problem. I can see a console before clearTimeout function. Is that consoling properly?